# Ver carpetas por separado android studio

Tags: android-studio

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo pasar en android studio de ver las carpetas como `com.xxx.xxx` a verlas como una dentro de otra en la vista de android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Estando en la vista de '`Project`' (View > Tool Windows > Project), seleccionas el modo Android en la parte superior izquierda, debajo de la barra de menús, y en la rueda ('Show options menu' si te pones encima) seleccionas para compactar o deseleccionas para extender la opción '`Compact Empty Middle Packages`'.